# How do I pass a new array as a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, parameter-passing

I am trying to use the following constructor:

```
public Tile(int top, int right, int bottom, int left, int _prefabIndex, bool _isDouble, int _villageIntake, bool _isControl, bool _isBuilder, bool[] _hasWater, int _homeVillage, int _isResevoir)
```

And I'm trying to use it in only one line of code for simplicity. I have tried using:

```
newTile = new Tile(1, 3, 1, 3, 12, false, -1, true, false, {false, true, false, false}, -1, -1);
```

But I get a compile error on the `Boolean` array parameter. I know I could use:

```
bool[] boolArray = {false, true, false, false};
newTile = new Tile(1, 3, 1, 3, 12, false, -1, true, false, boolArray, -1, -1);
```

But I am wondering if there is a correct syntax for passing a new array as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For:

```
private void Function(bool[] switches) ...
```

Do:

```
Function(new []{ true, false });
```

However, it's also useful to note that if you can make the array the last parameter, you can use the "params" keyword:

```
private void ParamsFunction(params bool[] switches) ...
```

...and do this:

```
ParamsFunction(true, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
new[]{false, true, false, false}
```

So it will be:

```
Tile(1, 3, 1, 3, 12, false, -1, true, false, new[]{ false, true, false, false}, -1, -1);
```

Comment: Worth noting to the question author: there's nothing special about this being passed to a constructor / method. In any place where such an expression is allowed, the `new [] { ... }` expression will create an array (with an inferred type) and produce a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public bool SetPriority(new []{high, medium, low})
{

}
```

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: Yes. It will compile

Comment: No, it will not. [See this SharpLab excerpt](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTQL5fV+0CAIwD2IiAQDKAU2AAFAE5gRS4AE8WAO2kB3AgG0AuuQAWYAOYmoBALbSYYAK43rEETu5sBlbAN7ZuIA===).